# Can I modify my 120v 30a soldering iron to be hotter? And how?

Tags: soldering

Not getting hot enough  and solder melts real quick and rolls away.

Comment: If the solder melts "real quick" then the iron is hot enough... It is experience that is required...

Comment: A 3.6kW iron doesn't sound like something you use for electronics...

Comment: A 30A soldering iron would be an absolute **monster.**   A 120VAC  outlet can't even deliver that much current.  Did you maybe mean 30W?

Comment: If the solder melts, it's getting hot enough. If the solder rolls away from where you want it to be, you are not getting the area you want to solder hot enough. You need to learn how to solder, don't blame your tools.

Answer (score 1):

No, do **NOT** modify the soldering iron. Although, I am confused as to *why* you want to do it. You say that you want it to be hotter, but you also say the solder melts real quick and rolls away.

To me, it doesn't sound like the iron isn't getting hot enough. It is likely that it needs to be cleaned. The tip may have gotten oxidised and it will affect the performance of the iron. You can get some bits to clean the tip such as a [brass wire sponge](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Aoyue-Soldering-Cleaner-Sponge-Needed/dp/B005C789EU) or you can use a [tip tinner](https://www.kitronik.co.uk/blog/clean-maintain-soldering-iron/) to help maintain the soldering iron.

Other than that, you just need to learn more skills in the use of the iron, and also how to look after it.